# Does RubyMine git integration need further configuration to work through a proxy?

Tags: git, proxy, rubymine

I am behind a firewall and RubyMine is not able to push to GitHub.

RubyMine has its proxy configuration set and it can perform a few network operations, which show that the proxy configuration is indeed working - but Git cannot push to GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git under RubyMine does not use the RubyMine proxy configuration.

The proxy configuration for Git should be done directly on git through the command line:

git config --global http.proxy server:port
git config --global https.proxy server:port

I think the same should apply to other JetBrains tools (like IntelliJ which I also use).